# embedding dublin core metadata in a webpage

Tags: metadata, dublin-core

I have already decided the structure of my  [Dublin Core Application Profile](http://dublincore.org/documents/profile-guidelines/) and the syntax and use of the [Dublin Core Element Set](http://dublincore.org/documents/dces/) for my web application.

But I never used before Dublin Core Metadata in general. So, allow me those simple questions.

About the Dublin Core Application Profile, I have to implement it with HTML and embed it on the header of the page?

About the Dublin Core Element Set, I will also use HTML to implement it. I'm going to use it for images. I will create fields in a table in my DB to store the values of the Set, for every image. When the image render to the end-user (via a gallery) should I also embed the values of the Set for this image? Something like

```
<img src="smiley.gif" alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42"
<meta name="DC.title" content="blah blah" />
//other 14 elements of the set here....
>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you provide Dublin Core metadata in the `head` of a HTML document, then this metadata applies to the whole document.

If you want to provide metadata only about a certain thing on that page (and this metadata is not applicable for other content on that page), you should not give it in the `head`.

Instead, you could use RDFa (e.g. [RDFa Lite 1.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdfa-lite/)) to annotate your content. Prefixes for the Dublin Core vocabulary are pre-defined in the [RDFa Core Initial Context](http://www.w3.org/2011/rdfa-context/rdfa-1.1):

> `dc` http://purl.org/dc/terms/
>   `dcterms` http://purl.org/dc/terms/
>   `dc11` http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/

You’d have to use/"mint" URIs for the things you want to describe on the page.

Answer (score 0):

yes that's how I would do it.  Interestingly, Or not)

If you look at DC's own site,

```
<img src="http://dcevents.dublincore.org/public/dc-images/dc2013-title.jpg" width="350" title="DC-2013 logo">
```

they don't seem to bother, or at least don't bother consistently